# How to add more than once node per zone in elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I want to deploy an elastic search cluster which has more than 3 nodes. However, during the configuration phase, maximum number of zones we can choose is 3, and maximum nodes per zone is limited to 1. There is a box which we can select the number of nodes, but it is greyed out. 
Please check the following image.
[image]

Please let me know how can I choose more than 1 nodes per zone, so that I can have more than 3 nodes for the cluster.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by scaling up: increase the RAM per node rather than the number of nodes. Once you have increased the RAM per node up to the maximum you can scale out by adding more nodes.